# What type of registers/timers do PIC MCUs use?

Tags: microcontroller, timer, counter, pic24f

[image]

> Timer1 has the following features:
>
> 16-bit timer/counter register pair
> (TMR1H:TMR1L)

What I can't understand is that I couldn't find on the Internet what actual sequential circuit is hiding beneath that mask  of "TMR1 (H-L)" register. Is it a shift-register or parallel-in-serial-out register or what? And what's that "Sync" block made of? I mean you have either an asynchronous ripple counter or a synchronous counter - is that "Sync" block a kind of "switch" that switches between the two modes of operation? However the datasheet says this: *Timer1 is
incremented on the rising edge of the external clock input signal at the T1CKI pin, which can be synchronized to the
microcontroller system clock or can run asynchronously.* Is there some clue or it is Microchip's those "dark secrets" which it would never reveal?

Comment: Who knows? Microchip doesn’t tell us,nor do they have to. I would expect the timer is a synchronous counter and the registers you read and write are most likely different in terms of how they transfer the data with the counter. On the read side it might be simple latches or d flip/flops. As for the ‘sync’ block - would need to read the datasheet carefully as it could mean many things. For external signals, they need to be synchronised with the internal clock to avoid metastability.this might be what they mean by ‘sync’.

Comment: Where did that block diagram come from and why are you trying to use it? Why don't you use the diagram in the datasheet which is way more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a more detailed diagram of the Microchip 16 bit timer/counter.

The counters are all up counters and almost certainly synchronous. In VLSI design there is very little point in using asynchronous counters.

The synchronous/asynchronous mode is useful when you use an external signal as a clock input to the counters. It gives you the option of synchronizing this signal to the internal system clocks. This can alleviate problems of meta-stability. This is unwanted or unpredictable behavior when a control signal and the clock arrive at the same time. Synchronous and asynchronous do not refer to the counter type simply the way in which the clock is generated.
[image]

Diagram from PIC18F66K80 family datasheet from Microchip

The synch block will look something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL5PF2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This chained register arrangement is designed to remove a ambiguous output from the first register caused by meta stability.  It settles before the next clock arrives to clock the output through the second register. Support for this being the circuitry is given by the 2 cycle delay caused by this block.

Answer (score 1):

From a [Microchip document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31012a.pdf) regarding TIMER1:

> When the prescaler is 1:1, the external clock input is the same as the
> prescaler output. The synchronization of T1CKI with the internal phase
> clocks is accomplished by sampling the prescaler output on alternating
> Tosc clocks of the internal phase clocks. Therefore, it is necessary
> for the T1CKI pin to be high for at least 2Tosc (and a small RC delay)
> and low for at least 2Tosc (and a small RC delay). Refer to parameters
> 45, 46, and 47 in the “Electrical Specifications” section.
>  When a
> prescaler other than 1:1 is used, the external clock input is divided
> by the asynchronous ripple-counter prescaler so that the prescaler
> output is symmetrical. In order for the external clock to meet the
> sampling requirement, the ripple-counter must be taken into account.
> Therefore, it is necessary for the T1CKI pin to have a period of at
> least 4Tosc (and a small RC delay) divided by the prescaler value.
> Another requirement on the T1CKI pin high and low time is that they do
> not violate the minimum pulse width requirements). Refer to parameters
> 40, 42, 45, 46, and 47 in the “Electrical Specifications” section.

You should be aware that these 16Fxxx series processors drive instruction cycles with a four-phase clock. It seems that "sync" uses two of these phases.
 For example, a 16 MHz oscillator drives the atomic instruction cycle at 4 million instructions/sec. In this case, "Tosc" is 1/(16x10^6).